# Reading from file bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having a hard time with the following bash script:

basically what the script does is receives a directory and then it searches in all of the folders that are in the directory  for files that end with .log. after that  it should print to the stdout all the lines from those files sorted by the date they were written in.

my script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name ".*log" | cat *.log |  sort --stable --reverse --key=2,3
```

when i run the script it does return the list but the sort doesnt work properly. my guess is because in some files there are \n which makes it start a new line.

is there a way to ignore the \n that are in the file while still having each line return on a new line?

thank you!
[image: the output we should be getting]
[image: current output result]
[image: text that is inside the files]

xxd command output:

ise@ise-virtual-machine:~$ xxd /home/ise/Downloads/f1.log
00000000: 3230 3139 2d30 382d 3232 5431 333a 3333  2019-08-22T13:33
00000010: 3a34 342e 3132 3334 3536 3738 3920 4865  :44.123456789 He
00000020: 6c6c 6f0a 576f 726c 640a 0032 3032 302d  llo.World..2020-
00000030: 3031 2d30 3154 3131 3a32 323a 3333 2e31  01-01T11:22:33.1
00000040: 3233 3435 3637 3839 206c 6174 650a       23456789 late.
ise@ise-virtual-machine:~$ xxd /home/ise/Downloads/f2.log
00000000: 3230 3139 2d30 392d 3434 5431 333a 3434  2019-09-44T13:44
00000010: 3a32 312e 3938 3736 3534 3332 3120 5369  :21.987654321 Si
00000020: 6d70 6c65 206c 696e 650a                 mple line.
ise@ise-virtual-machine:~$ xxd /home/ise/Downloads/f3.log
00000000: 3230 3139 2d30 382d 3232 5431 333a 3333  2019-08-22T13:33
00000010: 3a34 342e 3132 3334 3536 3738 3920 4865  :44.123456789 He
00000020: 6c6c 6f0a 576f 726c 6420 320a 0032 3032  llo.World 2..202
00000030: 302d 3031 2d30 3154 3131 3a32 323a 3333  0-01-01T11:22:33
00000040: 2e31 3233 3435 3637 3839 206c 6174 6520  .123456789 late
00000050: 320a                                     2.

Comment: try:   `find . -name "*.log" -exec cat '{}' \; | sort --stable --reverse --key=2,3`

Comment: It's not clear what is the ask - the \n is the line separator. Without it, you will not be able to read 'lines'

Comment: it is known that files for this script  start with the date, then there is some text and then each line ends with \0. the problem is that some lines in the files contain \n before the line is actually over which ruin the output. @dash-o

Comment: @DarrenSmith, I'd use `-exec cat '{}' +` to spawn fewer cat processes.

Comment: @c00kie_monster, you'll want to use the `-z` option for `sort` -- that tells sort that the records are null-terminated, not newline-terminated.

Comment: @glenn --- good tip!

Comment: @glennjackman what do you mean by null terminated?

Comment: @c00kie_monster consider editing the question to indicate that the lines are terminated with NUL (\0). This is important information

Comment: `\0` is known as a "null" byte.

Comment: Apart from the issue of the newline chraracter within the records,
I don't understand why you specify `--key=2,3` to `sort` while you mention
*files start with the date*.
Would you provide a few lines of the log file as an example?

Comment: @tshiono   i provided with few pictures : the first picture is the text that is inside the files, the second picture is the output i should be getting and the third picture is the current output i get

Comment: @c00kie_monster Thank you for providing the information. I'm wondering the lines in the log file are not terminated by a null character but just a newline. Would you please post the result of `xxd f1.log`? It would be preferable to post it as a text (just with copy & paste) rather than a picture. BR.

Comment: @tshinono i edited the post with the xxd command on each of the 3 files

Comment: @c00kie_monster I appreciate your effort. Your additional post is very informative and helpful. I've updated my answer accordingly. Would you please try it?

Answer (score 3):

Given that the entries in the log file are terminated with \0 (NUL), find, sed and sort can be combined:

```
find . -name '*.log' | xargs sed -z 's/\n//g' | sort -z --key=2,3 --reverse
```

Comment: I suppose the OP wants to preserve the newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

By assuming each record in the file starts with the date and the option `--key=2,3` is not necessary, please try:

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec cat '{}' \; | sort -z | xargs -I{} -0 echo "{}"
```

The final command `xargs .. echo ..` will be necessary to print properly the null-terminated lines.
If you still require `--key` option, please modify the code as you like. I'm not aware how the lines look like as of now.

**[UPDATE]**

According to the provided information by the OP, I assume the format of the log files
will be:

- Each record starts with the date in `"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.nanosec"` format
  and a simple dictionary order sort can be applied.
- Each record ends with `"\n\0"` except for the last record of the file
  which ends just with `"\n"`.
- Each record may contain newline character(s) in the middle as a part
  of the record for the line folding purpose.

Then how about:

```
find . -name "*.log" -type f -exec cat "{}" \; -exec echo -ne "\0" \; | sort -z
```

- `echo -ne "\0"` appends a null character to the last record of a file.
  Otherwise the record will be merged to the next record of another file.
- The `-z` option to `sort` treats the null character as a record separator.
- No other option to `sort` will be required so far.

Result with the posted input by the OP:

```
2019-08-22T13:33:44.123456789 Hello
World
2019-08-22T13:33:44.123456789 Hello
World 2
2019-09-44T13:44:21.987654321 Simple line
2020-01-01T11:22:33.123456789 late
2020-01-01T11:22:33.123456789 late 2
```

It still keeps the null character `"\0"` at the end of each record.
If you want to trim it off, please add the `tr -d "\0"` command
at the end of the pipeline as:

```
find . -name "*.log" -type f -exec cat "{}" \; -exec echo -ne "\0" \; | sort -z | tr -d "\0"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: tshiono and @dash-0 tnx for the help. i edited the post with pictures: 1st pic-  the output i should get, 2nd pic- current output, 3rd pic- text that is inside the files

Comment: @c00kie_monster Good to know it works. If you are confortable with my answer, I'd appreciate if you can
accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.

Comment: @c00kie_monster Thank you for the proposal of editing, but I'm afraid your suggestion lacks of the command line which is essential and most important.